# R curly braces syntax

Tags: r, syntax

It works, but I wonder why tis is correct

```
if (one_time_cost_year_zero != 0) { EIW_TPI_flag = 1 
} else {EIW_TPI_flag = 0}
```

while this results in an error

```
if (one_time_cost_year_zero != 0) { EIW_TPI_flag = 1 } 
else {EIW_TPI_flag = 0}
```

What's the logic behind that?

Comment: The REPL (== 'read-eval-parse loop') operates line by line. In your second example the first line is self-contained, ending in a closing `}` so the second line is ignored for that expression when parsed line by line -- and then constitutes a syntax error on the next line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because R would not know that your if -else statement is not finished yet (since only the `if ()`  line is also valid R...) compare

```
1 + 2
+ 3
```

vs

```
1 + 2 +
3
```

In R if we want to split a command over multiple lines we need to either leave a bracket open (as in the if -else example) or have a "hanging" operator at the end of the line (there are also "multiline" strings, but they are not really commands per se)....
Then, the error you are seeing results from the fact that we can't beginn a command with `else` (like we can't start a command with `in`, `|` etc.)

Accordingly, we could also write:

```
if (one_time_cost_year_zero != 0) { EIW_TPI_flag = 1 } else 
  {EIW_TPI_flag = 0}
```